# Other div options are not working

Tags: javascript

My javascript seems to have problem. The hover/selected state is only working on the first button to click. But when you click the others, the selected state is now working already.

```
$('.option-btn').click(function(){
    if ($('.option').hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

The result should be the user can click as many as he can. (Making several buttons to be active/selected)

Here's the sample fiddle:    http://jsfiddle.net/fdLfthnv/

Comment: `$('.option')` will return HTMLCollection where many elements having same class name, thus only for first element it is working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if ($('.option').hasClass('selected'))
```

to

```
if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fdLfthnv/2/)

UPDATE to answer OP's additional question:

Change your jquery to this:

```
$('.bet-offer div.option').click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            $(this).siblings().css('pointer-events', 'auto');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $(this).siblings().css('pointer-events', 'none');
        }
    });
```

Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1vuf1gm7/2/)

Comment: however, my client wants to disable the other buttons in a row if he selected already a button from that row. take a look at this (http://jsfiddle.net/1vuf1gm7/)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fdLfthnv/1/

`$('.option')` will return HTMLCollection, not each clicked item. Use `$(this)`

Do like this:

```
$('.option-btn').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change $('.option') to $(this) on the second line of your JavaScript:

```
$('.option-btn').click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/qbchar6L/